# Individual folder permissions within a document set

Tags: permissions, folder, document-set

I have a document library with document sets. The group permission for this document set is meant to be `Read`.

[image]

Beneath it there is a folder for working documents. The folder's permission is desired to be `Contribute`.

[image]

I can't seem to have those two different permissions.  Is that a "feature", or am I really missing something?

Answer (score 0):

what you see inside the library depends on the view which is active inside the document sets of this type.
Someone has maybe changed the column "Name" in the view from "linked to document with edit menu" to "linked to document".
This way you have the link to the document/folder/whatelse, but not the 3 dots available.

While not seeing the 3 dots you are still able to break inheritance with the help of the ribbon bar.
Mark the folder you need to break the inheritance and click on the ribbon "files". There you click on the button "Shared with" and in the dialoge on the button "Advanced". Now you are able to break the inheritance to your liking.
[image: Screenshot of the ribbon bar "files"]

Answer (score -1):

That is a feature, SharePoint does not out of the box support permission levels on folder structures.

Comment: Not true. You can break the inheritance down to the element and therefore the assigning of different permission levels for individuals and groups, anywhere.